# How can I get openstack VMs from a deployed VNF using tacker API with HTTP req?

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

How can I get VMs from a deployed VNF using tacker API with HTTP req?(not from cmd with tacker vnf-resource-list). i.e: curl?

Answer (score 0):

Tacker had provided a [restful API](https://docs.openstack.org/tacker/latest/contributor/api/mano_api.html) for that purpose:

For your case, you may want to use:

```
GET /v1.0/vnfs
```

Use curl to init a GET request, e.g.:

```
curl -k https://openstack ip/v1.0/vnfs
```

I haven't actually used it this way in production environment, but it shall clarify the basic idea.